# minimum value of $x^{\frac{x}{x+y+z+t}}\cdot y^{\frac{y}{x+y+z+t}}\cdot z^{\frac{z}{x+y+z+t}}\cdot t^{\frac{t}{x+y+z+t}}$

Tags: inequality

If $x,y,z,t\in N.$ Then maximum and minimum  value of $$x^{\frac{x}{x+y+z+t}}\cdot y^{\frac{y}{x+y+z+t}}\cdot z^{\frac{z}{x+y+z+t}}\cdot t^{\frac{t}{x+y+z+t}}$$

what i try

$$\frac{(x+x+\cdots \text{x times} )+(y+y+\cdots \text{y times})+(z+z+\cdots \text{z times})+(t+t+\cdots \text{t times})}{x+y+z+t}\geq \bigg(x^x\cdot y^y\cdot z^z \cdot t^t\bigg)^{\frac{1}{x+y+z+t}}$$

$$x^{\frac{x}{x+y+z+t}}\cdot y^{\frac{y}{x+y+z+t}}\cdot z^{\frac{z}{x+y+z+t}}\cdot t^{\frac{t}{x+y+z+t}}\leq \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2}{x+y+z+t}$$

how do i find minimum value of expression help me please

Comment: isn't the minimum value $0$ ? Let three of your variables be $0$ and the fourth be $1$.

Comment: It seems you didn’t provide the complete problem - viz. the options among which to choose minimum and maximum.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  Let $x=y=z=t$, then the expression becomes $t$, which can be made equal to any $t\in \mathbb N$… now what can you conclude on minimum or maximum (if it exists)?

---

**P.S.** It seems the OP really wanted to show the expression is $\geqslant \frac14(x+y+z+t)$.  For this, from homogeneity (we may extend the domain to positive reals as $\mathbb N$ is a subset), we may assume $x+y+z+t=4$, so that it is enough to show:
$$\prod_{x, y, z, t} x^x \geqslant  1 \iff \sum_{x, y, z, t} x \log x \geqslant 0$$
which follows directly from Jensen's inequality on the convex function being summed.

Comment: but minimum is given $\frac{x+y+z+t}{4}$

Comment: And if $x,y,z,t \in \mathbb N$, what is the minimum value of $\frac{x+y+z+t}{4}$?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum is $1$ and occurs for $x=y=z=t=1.$

The maximal value does not exist. Tty $x=y=z=t\rightarrow+\infty.$

Comment: but minimum is given $\frac{x+y+z+t}{4}$

Comment: @jacky Where it's given?

Comment: it is a objective problem.options as $(a) \frac{x+y+z+t}{4}\;\; (b)\; \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2}{x+y+z+t}\; (c)\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{4}}\; (d)\; \sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3}{4}}$

Comment: Now, try $x=y=z=t\rightarrow+\infty$ or $x=y=z=t=1$.